# Facebook Like button not working for people not logged into Facebook

Tags: facebook-like

My Facebook Like button does not work for those not logged into Facebook. They press the "Like" button and the login window appears for Facebook. When they enter their information and submit, an HTTP 500 error pops up.  I followed the Facebook developer code to put the "Like" button on the page.  Any ideas?

http://www.thebleepkidssay.com

Answer (score 1):

This maight be facebook app restriction issue. Try to set peoples age who can see your app, from 18 to 13 8for example

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could try - first of all your code is kind of mess. There are two `<html>` (and there should only be one) tags opened and only one gets closed for example. Also, your using

```
<fb:like href="http://www.thebleepkidssay.com" send="true" layout="button_count" width="300" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

to call your button. You might try

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.thebleepkidssay.com" data-send="true" data-width="300" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

instead (this is the format that is generated if you use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ to get your button).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I was trying to put XFBML type code in which is why I had the html line (which was incorrect, thank you!) and the call to the button in the fashion I had it. I have since changed back to HTML5 which mean removing the html tag and changing the button code to what you have below.  It still doesn't work though.  I saw a bug on the Facebook Bug page, has anyone tried this on their page lately? Maybe a bug?  Or do you see anything in my code now that could be incorrect?  Thank you soo much!  This is driving me crazy.

Comment: I changed my code yet again so that ALL code associated with the "like" button is from Add This. Still...no workie. I then searched the net and found a blog on a similar issue. They had a like button just like mine...no workie either.  I am thinking maybe Facebook is having issues. Hopefully that is the problem!  Otherwise, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I think it's very likely it is a Facebook issue because there are now two bug reports (one marked as duplicate) with people responding to both that they are having the same issue. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/347759798609016 is the first and https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/211127232325788 is the second

Comment: It seems it was a bug. They reported it as fixed but it isn't completely fixed.  Now, if a person is logged in and "likes" the page, all is good. If someone isn't logged in and "likes" the page, the login works fine, the pop up and everything looks good.  It does post to their wall that they liked the page but it does not show the page as a like in their info.  And, they don't pop into the open graph admin fan page.  Can anyone reproduce this?  Basically, try to "like" a page when not logged in and see if it actually pops in as a "like" in you info (not just on your wall).